# Strange method behaviour for second run

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, fuzzy-logic

I am writing an Arduino program that use a fuzzy logic to control the car, but I have problems with the C++, as the program behaves really strange. The first run gets me RIGHT results, but next runs shifts outputs in the array really strange way.

**EDIT:** I found out, that the problem is related to the number of FSets stored in the TermSet. If I put into TermSet more than 5 FSets, IT gives WRONG results only in the 3rd, 4th and 5th iteration. Other iterations gives RIGHT results.

My execution code is:

```
// Setup the FSets    
FSet errZ(0,2,0);   
FSet errDtZ(0,0.5,0);
FSet cntZ(0,4,0);   

//Setup the TermSets
TermSet errDt(-1,1,0.1,1);
TermSet err(-3,3,1,1);
TermSet cnt(-6,6,0.5,1);


void loop(){  

  //Fill the TermSets with FSets      
  int ierrDt = errDt.addFSet(&errDtZ);

  int ierr = err.addFSet(&errZ);       

  int icnt = cnt.addFSet(&cntZ);      

  //Create a single FRule for test
  //Passing in the errZ, errDtZ and cntZ FRules
  FRule rule1(&err,ierr,&errDt,ierrDt,&cnt,icnt);

  //Test if the cntZ FRule gives every loop correct answers
  // It shows up, that it does! - not included in output
  int j = 0;
  for(float i = -6; i <= 6; i = i + 0.5){
     Serial.print(i);
     Serial.print("/");
     Serial.print(cnt.getUODValue(j++));
     Serial.print(" - ");
     Serial.println(cntZ.lom(i));   
  }

  double x1 = -1.5;
  double x2 = 0.25;

  //
  Serial.println("===== SUMMARY =====");  
  // Call lom on FSets manualy - gives RIGHT RESULTS
  Serial.print("LOM1: ");
  Serial.println(errZ.lom(x1));

  Serial.print("LOM2: ");
  Serial.println(errDtZ.lom(x2));   
  Serial.println("===== END OF SUMMARY =====");   

  // Get the result of the rule - that gives sometime WRONG results
  double* output = rule1.ruleOutput(x1,x2);  

  // Output the returned array
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("------- Rule outputs -------");
  for(int i = 0; i < cnt.UODLength(); i++){ 
     Serial.print(cnt.getUODValue(i)); // Universe of discourse value X
     Serial.print(" - ");   
     Serial.println(output[i]); // Outputed value for the givend X that belongs to UOD
  }  

  delay(5000);  

}
```

This outputs something like this for 3 runs:
    // cntZ for WHOLE UOD - every run are correct - omitted from output in next runs
    `-6.00/-6.00 - 0.00`
    `-5.00/-5.00 - 0.00`
    `-4.00/-4.00 - 0.00`
    `-3.00/-3.00 - 0.25`
    `-2.00/-2.00 - 0.50`
    `-1.00/-1.00 - 0.75`
    `0.00/0.00 - 1.00`
    `1.00/1.00 - 0.75`
    `2.00/2.00 - 0.50`
    `3.00/3.00 - 0.25`
    `4.00/4.00 - 0.00`
    `5.00/5.00 - 0.00`
    `6.00/6.00 - 0.00`

```
RUN 1
===== SUMMARY =====
LOM1: 0.88 //THESE VALUES ARE ALWAYS OK
LOM2: 0.80 
===== END OF SUMMARY =====
LOM1 internal: 0.88 //THIS VALUE IS SOMETIMES WRONG - WHY?
LOM1 internal: 0.80
DOF internal: 0.80

LOM in -6.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -5.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -4.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -3.00 is 0.25
And output[i] is: 0.25
LOM in -2.00 is 0.50
And output[i] is: 0.50
LOM in -1.00 is 0.75
And output[i] is: 0.75
LOM in 0.00 is 1.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in 1.00 is 0.75
And output[i] is: 0.75
LOM in 2.00 is 0.50
And output[i] is: 0.50
LOM in 3.00 is 0.25
And output[i] is: 0.25
LOM in 4.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 5.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 6.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00

------- Rule outputs -------
-6.00 - 0.00
-5.00 - 0.00
-4.00 - 0.00
-3.00 - 0.25
-2.00 - 0.50
-1.00 - 0.75
0.00 - 0.80
1.00 - 0.75
2.00 - 0.50
3.00 - 0.25
4.00 - 0.00
5.00 - 0.00
6.00 - 0.00    


RUN 2

===== SUMMARY =====
LOM1: 0.88 //OK
LOM2: 0.80
===== END OF SUMMARY =====
LOM1 internal: 0.88 //OK
LOM1 internal: 0.80
DOF internal: 0.80

//HERE IT STARTS TO BE QUITE STRANGE
LOM in -6.00 is 0.00 
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -5.00 is 85827176.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in -4.00 is 107218432.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in -3.00 is 142783152.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in -2.00 is 213912576.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in -1.00 is 428873696.00
And output[i] is: 0.80
LOM in 0.00 is -0.00
And output[i] is: -0.00
LOM in 1.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 2.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 3.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 4.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 5.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 6.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00

------- Rule outputs -------
//RULE OUTPUTS TOTALLY MIXED UP
-6.00 - 0.00
-5.00 - 0.80
-4.00 - 0.80
-3.00 - 0.80
-2.00 - 0.80
-1.00 - 0.80
0.00 - -0.00
1.00 - 0.00
2.00 - 0.00
3.00 - 0.00
4.00 - 0.00
5.00 - 0.00
6.00 - 0.00    

RUN 3
===== SUMMARY =====
LOM1: 0.88
LOM2: 0.80
===== END OF SUMMARY =====
LOM1 internal: 0.00 //THAT IS WRONG VALUE
LOM1 internal: 0.80
DOF internal: 0.00

//WRONG AGAIN
LOM in -6.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -5.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -4.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -3.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -2.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in -1.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 0.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 1.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 2.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 3.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 4.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 5.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00
LOM in 6.00 is 0.00
And output[i] is: 0.00

//WRONG
------- Rule outputs -------
-6.00 - 0.00
-5.00 - 0.00
-4.00 - 0.00
-3.00 - 0.00
-2.00 - 0.00
-1.00 - 0.00
0.00 - 0.00
1.00 - 0.00
2.00 - 0.00
3.00 - 0.00
4.00 - 0.00
5.00 - 0.00
6.00 - 0.00
```

The classes code is:

```
//Class representing the fuzzy set
FSet::FSet(double center, double delta, int inf){

    this->inf = inf;
    this->delta = delta;
    this->a = center - delta;
    this->b = center + delta;
    this->center = center;
}

//Return the level of matching of some crisp value
double FSet::lom(double crispValue) {
    if(inf == 0){
        if((crispValue < this->a) || (crispValue > this->b)){
            return 0.0;
        } else {

            return 1 - abs(crispValue-center)*(1.0/delta);
        }
    } else {
        if( ((crispValue < this->a) && (inf > 0)) ||
                ((crispValue > this->b) && (inf < 0))){
                return 0.0;
        }

        if((inf > 0) && (crispValue < center)){
            return 1 - abs(crispValue-center)*(1.0/delta);
        } else if((inf < 0) && (crispValue > center)){
            return 1 - abs(crispValue-center)*(1.0/delta);
        } else {
            return 1.0;
        }

    }

}


/*
 * Class that contains all the FuzzySets of the same variable
 * e.g.: TermSet err would include negativeErro, zeroError, positiveError etc.
 */
TermSet::TermSet(double a, double b, double step, int setsSize){
    //Boundaries of the Universe of discourse (UOD)
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    //Step for discretization of the UOD
    this->step = step;

    //Index of the last inserted FSet
    this->last = -1;
    //Number of FSets
    this->setsSize = setsSize;
    this->sets = (FSet**) malloc(sizeof(FSet*) * setsSize);

    // The length of the universe of discourse
    this->length = (b-a)/step + 1;
}

TermSet::~TermSet(){
    free(this->sets);
}

// Return the FSet by index
FSet* TermSet::getFSet(int index){
        return this->sets[index];
}

/* Adds FSet to the TermSet
 * return the index of the FSet in the array
 */
int TermSet::addFSet(FSet* set){
    sets[++last] = set;
    return last;
}

/* Get the value of the UOD that is n steps
 * right of the begging of the UOD
 */
double TermSet::getUODValue(int n){
    return a + n*step;
}

// Return the length of the UOD
int TermSet::UODLength(){
    return length;
}

 /*
 * Class representing the FuzzyRule of form:
 * IF error is positive AND change of error is positive THEN change of control is negative
 * Which in code is represented as:
 * IF x1 is ant1[U1] AND x2 is ant2[U2] THEN y is con[D]
*/

FRule::FRule(TermSet* ant1, int u1, TermSet* ant2, int u2, TermSet* conTermSet, int d){
    // TermSet for the antecedent part of the rule
    this->ant1 = ant1;
    this->ant2 = ant2;

    //Indexes of the FRules in the antacendents ant1 and ant2
    this->U1 = u1;
    this->U2 = u2;

    //TermSet for the consequent part
    this->con = conTermSet;
    //Index of the consequent FRule in the con TermSet
    this->D = d;

    // Array of the output values
    output = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * con->UODLength());
}

FRule::~FRule(){
    free(output);
}

/* Get the degree of firing of the antacendent part
 * that is return the min of the FSet->lom(x) values;
 */
double FRule::dof(double x1,double x2){
    double pi1 = ant1->getFSet(U1)->lom(x1);
    double pi2 = ant2->getFSet(U2)->lom(x2);

    Serial.print("LOM1 internal: ");
    Serial.println(pi1);
    Serial.print("LOM1 internal: ");
    Serial.println(pi2);

    return min(pi1,pi2);
}

double* FRule::ruleOutput(double x1, double x2){
    // Get the degree of firing of the antacendent part
    double adof = this->dof(x1,x2);
    Serial.print("DOF internal: ");
    Serial.println(adof);

    /* Iterate throw the universe of discourse of the consequent part and
     * combine the lom of the consequent with value with the dof value of
     * antacendent using the min operator
     */
    double j = con->a;
    for (int i = 0; i < con->UODLength(); i++){
        double dlom = con->getFSet(D)->lom(j);

        Serial.print("LOM in ");
        Serial.print(j);
        Serial.print(" is ");
        Serial.println(dlom);

        output[i] = min(adof,dlom);
        j = j + con->step;

        Serial.print("And output[i] is: ");
        Serial.println(output[i]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

I expect that the problem is in the `FRule->ruleOutput(double x1,double x2)` method, but I might be wrong. Also I think it must be some sort of memory problem, as I am new to C++ and not quite comfortable with the whole memory management.

Comment: Please present a complete, _minimal_ testcase. This is a lot of code.

Comment: Fixed title to state C++ rather than C. But do I have this right? Are you actually complaining because your fuzzy logic is ... fuzzy? :-)

Comment: I removed some unnecesary parts, but it is still a lot of code. Unfurtunately I think, that it is not possible to shorten it more.

C++ is right.
Well it sounds strange, but yes, I am:-)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are allocating an array of pointers, and not an array of FSet objects? This seems strange, where are the `FSet` variables allocated? Also, is there a reason why you aren't using a std::vector instead?

Comment: I am not allowed to use std::vector on arduino. I am allocating array of pointers, because I thought it would be more memory efficient than copping objects to array. Or am I wrong? (I have only 2048b of memory for variables) `FSet` objects are passed from the execution code (the loop function).

Answer (score 2):

`i = i++` might be the culprit. Modifying a variable twice like this in C or C++, without a sequence point in between, is undefined behavior.

You probably meant to write `i++`.

Comment: @MitchNajmitch And that would be why you should always copy/paste the actual code, if possible.